# Module uploaded to packagist but can not install via terminal

Tags: magento, composer-php, packagist

I have uploaded one of my magento 2 extension to github and submitted on packagist.Now when i am trying to install the same via command line,I can not install and getting error.
Please have a look over the attached screen-shot

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to add the version with the command which is uploaded on the packagist

Comment: I have tried both the things addded version also....but no luck

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a tag in repo on GitHub to create release - right now your package [does not have any releases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpZRT.png) that will match `alpha` stability.

Alternatively you may require `dev-master` explicitly - it will use `master` branch from your repo:

```
composer require vortex/geoip:dev-master
```

Comment: can you please explain how can i create tag in repo..thank you

Comment: You should have "Create a new release" button here: https://github.com/staywithabhi/vortex-geoip/releases . There is also link for git documentation, which explains how to do this using git.

Comment: Thankyou,as explained by you i have created new release for my module and updated on packagist also.Now when i am trying to install the same in my magento 2 instance i am still getting the same error.

Comment: Try wait a couple of minutes, Packagist may need a minute or two to process your new release to be visible by composer commands.

Comment: It has already been passed more than 15 mins but no luck so far.Please check original question I have added one more image containing error i am getting right now

Comment: This may be related to recent Packagist problems with mirrors cache, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52184874/5812455

Comment: Is there any way to clear the mirror cache for packagist
Or how long i need to wait inorder to see the changes
One more thing rob i have created a new release and packagist is also point to new version and still composer can not install the module

Comment: I can't help you with cache issues of Packagist mirrors - you need to ask maintainers for help.

Comment: thank you for the help.One more thing i have created new release and it is reflected on packagist but module is still not downloaded using composer.